# Move to searched text on active screen with pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

I am trying to make a program that searches for a text on a web-page, then places the mouse cursor on the highlighted text after it has been found. Is this possible using pyautogui? If so, how. If not, are there any other alternatives to do this?

Example code below:

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui


var = 'Filtered Questions'
webbrowser.open('https://stackexchange.com/')
time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.typewrite(var)
#code to place mouse cursor to the occurrence of var
```

I would prefer to not use the pyautogui.moveTo() or pyautogui.moveRel() because the text I am searching for on the website is not static. The position of the searched text varies when the web page loads. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question while researching the topic. Basically the answer is no. " major points:

1) Pyautogui has the option of searching using images. Using this you could for example screenshot all the text you want to find and save as individual text files then use that to search for it dynamically and move the mouse there/click/do whatever you need to. However, as explained in the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html), it takes 1-2 seconds for each search which is rather unpractical.

2) In some cases, but not always, using ctrl+f on a website and searching for the text will scroll so that the result is in the middle (vertical) of the page. However that relies on some heavy implications about where the text to search is. If it's at the top of the page you obviously won't be able to use that method, same as if it's at the bottom.

If you're trying to automate clicks and have links with distinguishable names, my advice would be to parse the source code and artificially clicking the link. Otherwise you're probably better off with a automation suite like blue prism.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that, but you additionally need Tesseract (and the Python-module pytesseract) for text recognition and PIL for taking screenshots.

Then perform the following steps:

1. Open the page
2. Open and perform the search (ctrl+f with pyautogui) - the view changes to the first result
3. Take a screenshot (with PIL)
4. Convert the image to text and data (with Tesseract) and find the text and the position
5. Use pyautogui to move the mouse and click on it

Here is the needed code for getting the image and the related data:

```
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab  # screenshot

import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (r"C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract") # needed for Windows as OS

screen =  ImageGrab.grab()  # screenshot
cap = screen.convert('L')   # make grayscale

data=pytesseract.image_to_boxes(cap,output_type=Output.DICT)

print(data)
```

In `data` you find all required information you need to move the mouse and click on the text.

The downside of this approach is the ressource consuming OCR part which takes a few seconds on slower machines.

Answer (score 4):

When you use Chrome or Chromium as a browser there is a much easier and much more stable approach using ONLY pyautogui:

1. Perform Crtl + F with pyautogui
2. Perform Ctrl + Enter to 'click' on search result / open the link related to the result

With other browsers you have to clarify if there keyboard shortcuts also exists.

Comment: This is awesome. So simple!

Answer (score 2):

If you are a newcomer looking for how to find a string of text anywhere on your screen and stumbled upon this old question through a Google search, you can use the following snippet which I have used in my own projects (It takes a raw string of text as an input, and if the text is found on the screen, return the coordinates, and if not, return None):

```
import pyautogui
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

# In case you're on Windows and pytesseract doesn't
# find your installation (Happened to me)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

def find_coordinates_text(text, lang='en'):
    # Take a screenshot of the main screen
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()

    # Convert the screenshot to grayscale
    img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # Find the provided text (text) on the grayscale screenshot 
    # using the provided language (lang)
    data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang=lang, output_type='data.frame')

    # Find the coordinates of the provided text (text)
    try:
        x, y = data[data['text'] ==
                    text]['left'].iloc[0], data[data['text'] == text]['top'].iloc[0]

    except IndexError:
        # The text was not found on the screen
        return None

    # Text was found, return the coordinates
    return (x, y)
```

Usage:

```
text_to_find = 'Filtered Questions'
coordinates = find_coordinates_text(text_to_find)
```

Comment: I got this error: ```pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/en.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'en\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')```

Comment: `en` as default lang is deprecated I think, instead it must be `eng`.

Answer (score 1):

pyautogui is for controlling mouse and keyboard and for automating other GUI applications. If your need is to find a text on a webpage, you may look for better options that are intended for scraping webpages. For instance: [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)